Как быть с разными операционными системами для обучения технологиям?
Вот я к примеру хочу изучить какую-то новую технологию, попрактиковаться. Но часто в курсах  или доках нет одного стандарта и у кого что стоит из операционок, начинают запускать свои команды там в консолях, а у меня зачастую не так гладко все идет... ошибки... как же я за**ался... и вот задаюсь вопросом какой тут лучше подход.
Как пользователю мне удобнее винда (сейчас у меня только 1 ноут с ней), как разработчику нормально и на винде и на маке (и то и то пробовал). На проде обычно образы линукса всякого на который я как пользователь не спешу переходить.
И вот о каких вариантах думаю:

Настраивать среду максимально похожую на ту про которую идет повествование? Вот известные подходы https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/5-ways-to-use-linux-on-a-windows-machine/. Но макОС же так не настроить как я понимаю...


windows subsystem for linux - не пробовал, может это мой шанс, но со стороны кажеться чем-то не полноценным. Полноценное ли это решение?
виртуалка с убунту. Что не удобно дергать окна туда сюда и потом искать где твой образ...
находить что-то через браузер. Звучит как или решение под очень узкие кейсы или как то что это брать в аренду EC2 и потом еще в долгах будешь...
второй операционной системой на ноут. Фигня, еще удалю основную случайно при установке, и потом полезно сразу 2 иметь одновременно работающие, а не по очереди.


Идти на пролом и пробовать использовать винду, тратить на это больше времени, выяснять почему ошибки в консоле, и может быть выяснить что в некоторых случаях она вообще не подходит в конкретном случае, но зато доходить до этого своим умом. А уже после этого переходить искать другие возможность... что повторно приведет к первоначальному вопросу.

Купить себе мак... или купть виндовый ноут и туда второй системой... но что-то не хотелось бы из-за моего кочевого бомжатского образа жизни при котором все свое нужно иметь возможность перенести с собой, плюс это расходы...



поставь линукс рядом с виндой

Сидеть на винде и не париться. Linux завести на дешевом хостинге и в него через ssh ходить.

Что-то как-то для разработчика очень заморочно. Разработчик работает на платформе, которая подходит для проекта. У вас будет или зоопарк из виртуальных машин или зоопарк из реальных машин.

Перейди на Линукс (о винде забудь)

Все зависит от конкретных технологий. Если что-то совсем низкоуровневое (ну мало ли, может драйвер для Linux пишите?), то только Linux. Разработка десктоп приложений - лучше тоже сразу на реальной системе (как минимум - на виртуалке с реальной системой). Для какого-нибудь бэкэнда wsl скорее всего будет достаточно.
